# ElasticSearch6 setup JavaHell Error in IntellijIDEA

Tags: elasticsearch, intellij-idea

While running ElasticSearch with argument -d (To daemonize) I am getting an exception :

```
[ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
class: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.package-info
jar1: /home/mightguy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.7.1/91840e1f4f0caec10aad4d460470a98db6a4cbe8/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.1.jar
jar2: /home/mightguy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.7.1/d6412e04f64f191bde1467c0662f1f014ac5dc85/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.1.jar
```

My VM variables are as follows:

```
> -Xms256m
> -Des.path.home=/home/mightguy/Dev/elasticsearch/core/
> -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true
```

I have already copied config folder from

> /distribution/src/main/resources/config/ To core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to remove the **jar hell** dependencies when you run it in **Intellij**. try to delete these dependencies directly:

```
rm /home/mightguy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.7.1/91840e1f4f0caec10aad4d460470a98db6a4cbe8/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.1.jar
rm /home/mightguy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.7.1/d6412e04f64f191bde1467c0662f1f014ac5dc85/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.1.jar
```